# Heavy tailed rather than normal distribution for a stock simulator

Tags: confidence-interval

Have a program that simulates picking stocks 10000 times according to different parameters. I then look at the ending portfolio amounts, and the distribution is pretty heavy tailed. This doesn't violate 'normal distribution rules', correct? I remember in undergrad that the normal distribution would appear if I took a mean of all 10000 ending portfolio amounts, and then did that like, many times. Is my understanding correct? Is there a ELI5 version of this phenomenon?

Secondly, I aim to calculate the confidence intervals for the ending portfolio amounts. I generate 10000 samples for ending portfolio amount and then sort these results. For a 70 percent CI, I pick the 3000th and 7000th sample from the sorted results. Is this correct? I think that's not correct; I remember in undergrad when calculating CI, we had to collect a random sample from the 10000, and then resample with replacement, and then take percentiles of the resampled results? Vaguely remember something like that.

Answer (score 1):

1. 

You’re alluding to the *[central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem)* (CLT), which says:

$$
\sqrt{n}\dfrac{
\bar X-\mu
}{
\sigma
}
\overset{d}{\rightarrow}
N(0,1)$$

(The $d$ above the arrow means a particular type of convergence in probability theory called [convergence in distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_distribution).)

Loosely speaking, the sample mean converges to a normal distribution as the sample size increases.

However, there are conditions on the observations used to calculate that $\bar X$. There are multiple variants of the CLT, but a commonality is a requirement that the observations used to calculate $\bar X$ come from distributions with finite variance.

Financial processes often are thought to be too heavy-tailed to have finite variance, so the central limit theorem would not apply.

Even if the variance is finite, the tails might be so heavy that a finite sample size does not get you particularly close to the limit. Vanderbilt’s Frank Harrell has [tweeted](https://twitter.com/f2harrell/status/1051917716402126849) about this, for instance.

2)

You’re alluding to *bootstrap* confidence intervals, particularly using a percentile bootstrap, which is easy to calculate but not considered a great method. Software like the `boot` package in `R` makes it easy to calculate preferred bootstrap confidence interval, such as bias-corrected and accelerated (BCa).

Comment: When calculating confidence intervals, is resampling vs non resampling a conversation to have? Or do you always have to resample?

Comment: Meaning like, let's say we are estimating US voting preferences and we have 10000 samples out of the 350million population. Resampling would makes sense in that case. However, what if we have (hypothetically), 340million samples. In that case, resampling would not make sense, correct?

Comment: For my finance example, specifically users enter into the calculator what edge they think they have on each trade, how much of their portfolio to commit to each trade (this can either be fixed or variant), and also how many trades they plan to make in the upcoming year.

Comment: There are lots of ways to calculate confidence intervals. The first way people tend to learn has to do with a z-statistic or t- statistic. The Pennsylvania State University has some [online lessons](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat200/lesson/4/4.2) about this topic.